# git pull / merge - ignore untracked and modified files that are the same as in the remote, complain if they differ

Tags: git

Is there a flag or a command that would make `git pull` or `git merge` not complain about modified and untracked files in the current working tree if those files have the same hash as the counterpart files in remote / source branch? At the same time, `git pull/merge` should complain if those files differ.

## Example:

```
$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   index.php
        modified:   bootstrap.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        config.php
        database.php
```

Let us assume that remote has already both `index.php` and `config.php` changes committed and that both local files are identical with their remote equivalents. At the same time, `bootstrap.php` is not identical, and  `database.php` is not yet tracked in the remote. I want to do `git pull`, but it'll complain about `index.php` being modified and `config.php` being untracked in the local branch but tracked in the remote branch. I don't want to run any command that would remove `database.php` nor revert changes to `bootstrap.php`. I don't want to handle this manually, as there might be a dozen or so files with such conflicts. I want `git pull` to complain about `bootstrap.php` and `database.php` though.

## Use case:

I code & commit on my local machine, and my IDE uploads changes to my dev server automatically. Both my local copy and dev server copy are usually the same (but not always for various reasons). For convenience reasons, I want from time to time to do on my dev server git pull and not have to resolve any conflicts that seem trivial to handle.

A similar use case is when I work with developers who don't like / don't know git / don't have access to the repo and upload code to production directly. I usually commit their changes on my local machine, do `git push` and then do `git pull` on the server. Even though the commit contains exactly the same files `git pull` will complain.

Comment: Stash, pull, unstash? Still feels like a regression just waiting to happen

Comment: There is no such flag. You'll need to change your workflow such that files that you need to modify locally are not part of the repository.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen good idea, but stash / unstash won't detect conflicts before `git pull`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a flag or a command that would make git pull or git merge not complain about modified and untracked files in the current working tree if those files have the same hash as the counterpart files in remote / source branch?

[Edit: on request, I snipped out a big chunk of what you can do about various situations that result in these kinds of problems. Use the edit history to see what was here before.]

No.  It's unfortunate: it would occasionally be nice.  (You can move your own files out of the way, do the operation, then put your own files back; be sure to `git rm --cached` any files that you don't want to go into the *next* commit, that came in via merge.)

Comment: I did answer your question. The answer is "no": you can't do that. There's nothing in Git that will do that. See the first line.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that and by the time I realized it I already couldn't edit my comment. I'm sorry about that. I would be happy to accept this as an answer. However, would you consider removing the rest of it (the part after "No")? As great as the rest of the answer is, I think it just does not belong here.

Comment: If you like - but there's a minimum length for StackOverflow answers, too. There will be some extra junk no matter what...

Answer (score 0):

Use `git checkout` with `--force` in order to throw away local changes.

I'd also re-think my workflow if I were you. Unversioned changes are problematic. If your teammates don't know how to use git, that's something that can be changed.

Comment: `git checkout --force` will remove tracked, modified files that are in conflict with the remote branch. As for "my workflow" - it's not "my workflow", it's what I need to deal with. In a perfect world, my employer would hire only qualified developers, but after working with dozens of clients as a freelancer, I can confidently say that's not the case (and I've worked for small, medium, and semi-big companies). Usually, my teammate who does not know git has been hired for one gig and nobody is going to invest money into them.